# How to Update API Stock Values with VBA running

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is - When the VBA Macro is running, the subscribed stock values do not update..

The intent is to have the VBA run with a timed interval until a specific trade condition is met.  Then a subsequent Excel file (Ranger) will execute the trade through IB / TWS

This requires that the stock values update when the VBA is in Wait mode.  Or it requires that a Copy / Paste will update the stock value in a specific "updated" location… Or Calcualte will …

Data is through MarketXLS.com.  I had the same problem with data feeds from TDA and TWS.

> Excel 2016 Small Business 64 bit
>      Windows 10 Pro 64 bit Vs. 1803
>      Computer: i7-6950X, 128GB / 3200 RAM, Samsung M.2 960 Pro 500GB SSD

The following was written to check to see if the values were updating.  (They were not updating).

```
Range("D50:AN59").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D60").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
Calculate
Calculate
Range("D60:AN69").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))
Range("D50:AN59").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D60").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
Calculate
Calculate
Range("D60:AN69").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

When the above runs, the values do not update.  Ideally, the values in the different copied sets will be different.

The data in rows 50 though 59 will update continuously when the VBA is not running.  The data sets in rows 60 and below are from the "timed" copy paste of the values in rows 50 though 59

```
    Ford (F)    Security->> AAPL    F
    Formula NOW()  V        
QM_Stream_Last(F$10)    9.535   12:08:18 PM 209.43  9.535
Last(F$10)  9.575   12:08:18 PM 209.34  9.575
rt_Last(F$10)   9.535   12:08:18 PM 209.43  9.535
Volume(F10) 383492  12:08:18 PM 550755  383492
rt_Volume(F10)  15631750    12:08:18 PM 10626521    15631750
QM_Stream_AccumulatedVolume(F10)    15634708    12:08:19 PM 10695630    15634708
```

Comment: needs some formatting done on this question.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code tried. not sure the bottom part is salvageable without OP's intervention though